# _SESSION['xxx'] not being retained across pages in my web application

Tags: php, html, session

I have an html file which has inline php.  The index.html looks roughly as follows

```
<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['xxx']; ?>
<form action=blah.php> ... </form>
```

And in blah.php, I do a

```
    $_SESSION['xxx'] = "foo";
    header('Location: index.html');
```

However, when index.html is shown for the second time, I do not see the "foo" message.

Comment: Are you using `session_start()`?

Comment: Yes, in both the HTML and the PHP.

Comment: Are you sure the PHP code is being parsed in the HTML file?

Comment: Yes.  Any other PHP statement works.

Comment: Strange. And from your code I take it you are never switching domains? (Not even `www.domain.com` against `domain.com`)

Answer (score 0):

Then check your server settings. Try to set send session values in address line (like GET request).

Answer (score 0):

Run this bit of code before your starting your session.  It's possible there is an error accessing the session file

```
ini_set("display_errors", "stdout"); error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP cannot parsed by HTML files, I mean PHP codes cannot run by HTML,  you can try like

```
<!--#include FILE="test.inc" -->
```

Above code is HTML file include and put your PHP codes in .inc file, but you have to make some changes in Apache